# "I consider it true" or "I consider it to be true"?

Tags: word-choice

Which one is correct or more correct?

> I consider it to be true.

or

> I consider it true.

Or maybe both?

According to Google Ngram Viewer both are used with the second being more common. [Google Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=consider%20it%20true%2Cconsider%20it%20to%20be%20true&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cconsider%20it%20true%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cconsider%20it%20to%20be%20true%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: What does your research tell you?

Answer (score 0):

To my ears, **I consider it to be true** is better than **I consider it true** in British English.